# overlay 3 elements of top of each other HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, position, tailwind-css, absolute

What is the best way to overlay 3 elements in html css? I have tried this and doesn't work.
I am trying to overlay two images, filter image offers specific lighting for the one below, and then on top of those two images will be two paragraphs.
Can this be done?  Any suggestions are welcomed.

[image: screen]

```html
    <div class="parent">
     <img src="image"   class="main-pic"/>
     <img src="transparent filter for image"   class="filter"/>
     <div class="text">
      <h3 class="title"> title </h3>
      <p class="intro" > bio paragraph </p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    .parent {
     position: relative;
    }

    .image {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 0;
    }

    .filter {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .text {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use nested divs for this. Below is the example

```css
.grandparent {
 padding:10px;
 background-color: blue;
}


.parent {
 padding:50px;
 background-color: gray;
}

.child{
 margin-left:30%;
 padding:25px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h3 class="title"> Name </h3>
      <p class="intro" > This is my portfolio </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mohit, I was actually trying to overlay two pictures and on top of those to place some paragraphs. Can this be done?

Combining the two images in one, doesn't offer a solution due pixilation on responsive layout

Comment: I answered the question you asked, so upvote first. Secondly please raise another question or look over SO for your next query.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote, what do you mean by "SO"?